# angular 2 typescript create singletone

Tags: angular, typescript

im new to typescript and angular 2 and what im trying to do is to create singletone to be used where ever is needed, but im getting this error:

```
Unexpected value 'ViewHelperComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

in the browser log, what am i doing wrong?

this is the class:

```
export class ViewHelperComponent {

static instance : ViewHelperComponent;

constructor() {}

public static getInstance(){
  if(ViewHelperComponent.instance == null)
     ViewHelperComponent.instance = new ViewHelperComponent();
  return ViewHelperComponent.instance;
}

check(){
  console.log("working");
}
}
```

and im calling it from this component:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ViewHelperComponent } from '../view-helper/view-helper';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-parent',
  templateUrl: './input-parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-parent.component.css']
})
export class InputParentComponent implements OnInit {

temp : ViewHelperComponent;

constructor() {
  this.temp = ViewHelperComponent.getInstance()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to program a singleton manually. You need a singleton service, not a component, and Angular will do it for you if you'll just declare the provider for this service in the module. For example, you can create the following class:

```
class ViewHelper {

   check(){
      console.log("working");
  }
}
```

Declare it in the providers property of `@NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({ ...
   providers: [ViewHelper]
})
```

Now you can use it in any component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-parent',
  templateUrl: './input-parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-parent.component.css']
})
export class InputParentComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private viewHelper: ViewHelper) {
  this.viewHelper.check();
 }
}
```

If you declare the provider in `@NgModule`, Angular will create a singleton instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly In the `app.module.ts` file you need to bootstraping the 'ViewHelperComponent' in the `@NgModule`,
for example:

```
@NgModule({ bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
   declarations: [
         AppComponent,
         ViewHelperComponent]...
```

Greetings!